# Поиск расположения глобального класса в composer

Tags: composer

Добрый день. Столкнулся с проблемой внедрения менеджера зависимостей composer в проект, где пространства имен не использовались впринципе. Возникла проблема при описании глобального пространства имен, т.е. в composer.json я пишу:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "mynamespace\\": "src/classes",
        "\\": "src/global"
    }
}
```

То есть пытаюсь указать, что все классы, в которых пространство имен не прописано, и к которым доступ осуществляется через \ (\User), лежат в папке src/global. Но в таком случае, такие глобальные классы все равно не находятся и приходится использовать require_once. В случае с mynamespace\ все отрабатывает штатно. 
Спасибо за внимание!

Comment: насколько понимаю, нужно указывать пустую строку, а не `"\\"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел решение в использовании параметра classmap (https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#classmap - This map is built by scanning for classes in all .php and .inc files in the given directories/files.):

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": ["src/global"]
}
```

Также, для исключения автоматической загрузки классов из указанных директорий можно использовать параметр exclude-from-classmap.
Может кому-то пригодится.